# unable to update progress bar in python progressbar2

Tags: python

```
import string
from ctypes import windll
from glob import glob
import os
import time
import progressbar
global totalFiles

def read_drives(drive):
    totalFiles=0
    totalDirs=0
    l=os.listdir(drive)
    l=len(l)
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=l)
    for  base, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        #print('Searching in : ',base)
        for directories in dirs:
            totalDirs+=1
            bar.update(totalDirs)
        for Files in files:
            totalFiles +=1

def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter)
        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lis = get_drives() 
    read_drives(lis[2]+':\\')
```

Still no solution please help, shows this error - "ValueError: Value 32 is out of range, should be between 0 and 31"
I need to show the progress bar while its searching for the number of directories in the "drives".

Answer (score 0):

```py
        for directories in dirs:
            bar.update(totalDirs)
        for Files in files:
            totalFiles +=1
```

You are not increasing `totalDirs` anywhere. Why do you expect the progress bar to change its value ? The bar actually *does* update itself, but you don't see that, because you are throwing the same 0 at it again and again.
You have to increase `totalDirs` the same way you do it with `totalFiles`:

```py
        for dir in dirs:
            totalDirs += 1
            bar.update(totalDirs)
        for file in files:
            totalFiles += 1
```

EDIT:
You are setting the maximum  value of the progressbar to the number of directories in the toplevel directory drive, but later adding the directories that are in these directories to totalDirs. You have to count the directories recursively. Your complete `read_drives` code should look like this:

```py
def read_drives(drive):
    totalFiles = 0
    totalDirs = 0
    l = 0
    for  base, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        l += len(dirs)

    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=l)
    for  base, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        for directories in dirs:
            totalDirs += 1
            bar.update(totalDirs)
        for Files in files:
            totalFiles += 1
```

Comment: ValueError: Value 32 is out of range, should be between 0 and 31 showing this error when i do that, Actually I did that back then but pushed the wrong piece of code in stack

Comment: STILL NO SOLUTION PLEASE HELP

Comment: @SIMPLESTUPIDTHINGS this is because you set the maximum value of the progressbar to the number of directories in the toplevel directory `drive`, but later adding the directories that are in these directories to `totalDirs`. You have to count the directories recursively.

Comment: can you give help me with that

Comment: @SIMPLESTUPIDTHINGS look into my post, I edited it

Comment: @SIMPLESTUPIDTHINGS my fault : I set the max_value of the PrpgressBar to 0 ! The new code should work now,